# Wordpress to app (android and ios)

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to transfer entire site to phone app? I have website on wordpress. It's responsive .  And I want create app that will display my website. And work exactly like in regular browser but only with my website and also with social networks (I'm taking some feeds and comments from them). Any suggestions or tutorials.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many plugins that offer what you are looking for. Mobiloud and Apppresser are two that come to mind.

Comment: http://wphc.julienrenaux.fr is open source and free